# Scala idiom for ordering by multiple criteria

Tags: scala, sorting, functional-programming, compareto

I want to do something like this:

```
class Foo extends Ordered[Foo] {
   val x
   val y
   val z
   .
   .
   .
   .
   def compare(that: Foo) = {
      val c0 = this.length compareTo that.length          // primary comparison
      lazy val c1 = this.x compareTo that.x               // secondary comparison
      lazy val c2 = this.y.size compareTo that.y.size     // tertiary comparison
      lazy val c3 = this.z.head compareTo that.z.head     // final tie breaker
      if (c0 != 0) c0 else if (c1 != 0) c1 else if (c2 != 0) c2 else if (c3 != 0) c3 else c4
   }    
}
```

I was wondering if there was any cleaner way to write this kind of thing. I am expecting some thing like `Ordering.multipleBy(ordering: Ordered[A]*)` signature which takes a varargs of comparables and selects first non zero.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is often better to use `Ordering` instead of `Ordered`. `Ordering` is a type class and is much more flexible than `Ordered` (if only because `Ordered` must be implemented by the type to compare, while with `Ordering` you can define this outside). To define the natural ordering (default `Ordering` instance) for your type, you just define an implicit ordering value in the companion object.

So, enough with the preamble. The nice thing is that when using `Ordering` what you want to do is pretty simple, as there is an implicit ordering for tuples (provided that the tuple elements themselves have a orderings)`:

```
object Foo {
  implicit val FooOrdering = Ordering.by{ foo: Foo => 
    (foo.length, foo.x, foo.y, foo.z) 
  }
}
```

In addition, there is an implicit conversion that converts any value that has an `Ordering` type class instance into an `Ordered` value (see `Ordered.orderingToOrdered`) so we have nothing special to do to automagically being able to pass any instance of `Foo` to a function that expects an `Ordered[Foo]`)

---

**UPDATE**: Concerning your new question:

> Slightly related - is there any way to compose orderings?

One way to do it would be to use mostly the same technic based on `Ordering.by` and conversion to tuples, but explicitly passing the orderings to compose:

```
val byXOrdering = Ordering.by{ foo: Foo => foo.x }
val byYOrdering = Ordering.by{ foo: Foo => foo.y }
val byZOrdering = Ordering.by{ foo: Foo => foo.z }

// Compose byXOrdering and byYOrdering:
val byXThenYOrdering = Ordering.by{ foo: Foo => (foo, foo) }(Ordering.Tuple2(byXOrdering, byYOrdering))

// Compose byXOrdering and byYOrdering and byZOrdering:
val byXThenYThenZOrdering = Ordering.by{ foo: Foo => (foo, foo, foo) }(Ordering.Tuple3(byXOrdering, byYOrdering, byZOrdering))
```

But it is relatively "noisy".
I could not find anything better using only the standard library, and so I would actually advise to use our own helper:

```
final class CompositeOrdering[T]( val ord1: Ordering[T], val ord2: Ordering[T] ) extends Ordering[T] {
  def compare( x: T, y: T ) = {
    val comp = ord1.compare( x, y )
    if ( comp != 0 ) comp else ord2.compare( x, y )
  }
}
object CompositeOrdering {
  def apply[T]( orderings: Ordering[T] * ) = orderings reduceLeft (_ orElse _)
}
implicit class OrderingOps[T]( val ord: Ordering[T] ) extends AnyVal {
  def orElse( ord2: Ordering[T] ) = new CompositeOrdering[T]( ord, ord2 )
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
val byXOrdering = Ordering.by{ foo: Foo => foo.x }
val byYOrdering = Ordering.by{ foo: Foo => foo.y }
val byZOrdering = Ordering.by{ foo: Foo => foo.z }

// Compose byXOrdering and byYOrdering:
val byXThenYOrdering = byXOrdering orElse byYOrdering

// Compose byXOrdering and byYOrdering and byZOrdering:
val byXThenYThenZOrdering = byXOrdering orElse byYOrdering orElse byZOrdering
```

Or even simpler, like this:

```
// Compose byXOrdering and byYOrdering:
val byXThenYOrdering = CompositeOrdering(byXOrdering, byYOrdering)

// Compose byXOrdering and byYOrdering and byZOrdering:
val byXThenYThenZOrdering = CompositeOrdering(byXOrdering, byYOrdering, byZOrdering)
```

`CompositeOrdering.apply` is basically what you called `Ordering.multipleBy` in your question.

Comment: I think you meant "Ordering is a type class and is much more flexible than Ordered" instead of "Ordering is a type class and is much more flexible than Ordering". :)

Comment: Lol, yes indeed. Thanks for reporting this, this is now fixed.

Comment: Slightly related - is there any way to compose orderings? For example, I have `AgeOrdering: Ordered[Person]` and `HeightOrdering: Ordered[Person]` and I want to create `AgeThenHeightOrdering: Ordered[Person]`

Comment: I think more concisely, the following would work:

`val byXThenYOrdering = Ordering.by{ foo: Foo => (foo.x, foo.y) }`

And yes, it'll be limited to the cardinality limit of tuples.

Comment: @XianXu: Maybe I am missing something, but isn't it exactly what I recommended in the first part of my answer...? The second part was only in response to a comment that I treated like another question. If you were precisely referring to that second question, then your code snippet is irrelevant as the question was how to compose existing `Ordering` instances, and not how to make this particular example more concise.

Answer (score 5):

If you want maximal speed--not what you asked for, I know!--and still decent clarity, you can

```
def compare(that: Foo): Int = {
  this.length compareTo that.length match { case 0 =>; case c => return c }
  this.x      compareTo that.x      match { case 0 =>; case c => return c }
  this.y.size compareTo that.y.size match { case 0 =>; case c => return c }
  this.z.head compareTo that.z.head match { case 0 =>; case c => return c }
  0
}
```

There are various nice collection-based and other solutions also, which I will leave to others to explain.  (Note all the boilerplate and observe that all you really need to know is `_.length` in each case...which motivates a `compareBy`, for example.)

Answer (score 3):

The best I can think of is this:

```
def compare(that: Foo) = multiCompare(
  this.length compareTo that.length      // primary comparison
  this.x      compareTo that.x,          // secondary comparison
  this.y.size compareTo that.y.size,     // tertiary comparison
  this.z.head compareTo that.z.head,     // final tie breaker
)

def multiCompare(c: ( => Int)*) = c find {_ != 0} getOrElse 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `Ordered` and `Ordering` if you can. The easiest way to sort by multiple criteria is to use `sortBy`. Here is an example:

```scala
val foos: Seq[Foo] = ???
foos.sortBy(f => (f.x, f.y, f.z, ...))
```

If you really want to implement `Ordered` I suggest you look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19348339/1262728

If you really want an `Ordering`, the simplest way to write one is as follows:

```scala
val fooOrdering: Ordering[Foo] = Ordering.by(f => (f.x, f.y, f.z))
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this syntax because it's self-documenting:

```
  val compositeOrdering: Ordering[Foo] =
    Comparator.comparing[Foo, CustomType](_.x, new ExplicitOrderingForCustomType)
    .thenComparingDouble(_.y)
    .thenComparingInt(_.z)
    .compare
```

It's constructing a composite `java.util.Comparator`, then casting its `compare` method to `scala.math.Ordering`