# Use of ordering to sort array of arrays, ascending and descending

Tags: arrays, scala, sorting

I would like to sort an array of tuples by 3rd and first element so I used the following code:

```
import scala.util.Sorting
val pairs = Array(("a", 5, 2), ("c", 3, 1), ("b", 1, 3))

// sort by the 3rd element, then 1st
Sorting.quickSort(pairs)(Ordering[(Int, String)].on(x => (x._3, x._1)))
```

My question is that, in the previous example I can sort by both the third and the first elements ascending or both of them descending (use reverse). but how to sort by the third element ascending and the 1st element descending.

Please, in your answer consider the following case:

```
Array[Array[People]]
```

where in this case I do not know the exact size of the inner array (depends on the file schema that I read into this array) and I want to sort by all the items in side (some ascending and some descending).

Edit:
It looks like, i got miss understood.

Here is my full case:
I have the following classes:

```
  sealed trait GValue extends Serializable with Ordered[GValue]{
def compare(o: GValue): Int = {
  o match {
    case GDouble(v) => this.asInstanceOf[GDouble].v compare v
    case GString(v) => this.asInstanceOf[GString].v compare v
  }
}

case class GDouble(v: Double) extends GValue

case class GString(v: String) extends GValue
```

and i want to do a code like this.

```
// (startInterval, StopInterval, ArrayOfColumns)
    val intervals: Array[(Long,Long,Array[GValue])] =
Array((10,20,Array(GDouble(10.2), GString("alarm"), GString("error"),GDouble("100.234"))),
    (30,2000,Array(GDouble(-10.2), GString("alarm"), GString("warn"),GDouble("0.234"))))
```

The schema or the inner array would change based on the input file (in the example it is Double,String, String, Double but it might be Double, Double or something else).
I would like to find a way to sort with out covering all the cases of the inner array (in regards to type and length), ascending and descending.

what i do currently is to change the inner array to Iterable and then use  Ordering[Iterable[GValue]] for sorting or  Ordering[Iterable[GValue]].reverse. But i want to sort in separated directions (ascending for the first column and then descending for the second then ascending to the third and so on)

Comment: You want to sort the `intervals` array based on some of the elements of the `Array[GValue]` ?

Comment: @Peter Neyens, Yes, You are totally right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Régis Jean-Gilles' `CompositeOrdering` from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14696410/5020846), we can compose multiple `Orderings`.

```
// Ordering to sort an Array[GValue] by column "col"
def orderByColumn(col: Int) = Ordering.by { ar: Array[GValue] => ar(col - 1) }

val `By Col3-Desc/Col1` = 
  CompositeOrdering(orderByColumn(3).reverse, orderByColumn(1))

val `By Col1/Col2/Col3` = 
  CompositeOrdering(orderByColumn(1), orderByColumn(2), orderByColumn(3))
```

Now we can sort an array of type `Array[GValue]`, and you could sort your `intervals` using `sortBy` :

```
intervals.sortBy(_._3)(`By Col3-Desc/Col1`)
```

If you want to sort the `intervals` array with `Sorting.quickSort`, we need an `Ordering` for the tuple :

```
type Interval = (Long, Long, Array[GValue])
implicit object tupleByArray extends Ordering[Interval] {
  def compare(a: Interval, b: Interval) = a._3 compare b._3
}
```

Now you can sort your `intervals` using `Sorting.quickSort`:

```
implicit val arrOrd = `By Col3-Desc/Col1`
Sorting.quickSort(intervals)

// Array[(Long, Long, Array[GValue])] = 
// Array(
//  (30,2000,Array(GDouble(-10.2), GString(alarm), GString(warn),  GDouble(0.234))), 
//  (10,20,Array(GDouble(10.2), GString(alarm), GString(error), GDouble(100.234)))
// )
```

---

*I leave my answer from before the question was updated :*

There is a [great article by Eric Loots](http://reactive.xploregroup.be/blog/8/Sorting-on-multiple-fields-and-Tuples) on sorting on multiple fields.

In your case of `Array[People]` this could look like :

```
case class People(name: String, age: Int)

object PeopleOrdering {
  // sort by name descending and age ascending
  implicit object `By Name-Rev/Age` extends Ordering[People] {
    def compare(a: People, b: People): Int = {
      import scala.math.Ordered._
      implicit val ord = Ordering.Tuple2[String, Int]
      (b.name, a.age) compare (a.name, b.age)
    }
  }
}

val people = Array(People("Alice", 40), People("Bob", 50), People("Charlie", 20))
Sorting.quickSort(people)(PeopleOrdering.`By Name-Rev/Age`)
// > people
// Array[People] = Array(People(Bob,20), People(Bob,50), People(Alice,40))

val array = Array(people, Array(People("B", 1), People("C", 2)))
array.foreach(ps => Sorting.quickSort(ps)(PeopleOrdering.`By Name-Rev/Age`))
// > array
// Array[Array[People]] = Array(
//   Array(People(Bob,20), People(Bob,50), People(Alice,40)), 
//   Array(People(C,2), People(B,1))
// )
```

Comment: Thanks, it was so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For your example where you want to order `String`s desceding add this before sorting

```
  implicit object ReverseStringOrdering extends Ordering[String] {
    def compare(x: String, y: String) = -1 * x.compareTo(y)
  }
```

So, in general just add implicit `Ordering` object of type you want to sort descending with overridden `compare` method. This solution works only if you sort by different types.

If you want to sort by first item ascending and second descending add this before sorting:

```
 implicit def AscFirstDescSecondTuple2[T1, T2](implicit ord1: Ordering[T1], ord2: Ordering[T2]): Ordering[(T1, T2)] =
    new Ordering[(T1, T2)]{
      def compare(x: (T1, T2), y: (T1, T2)): Int = {
        val compare1 = ord1.compare(x._1, y._1)
        if (compare1 != 0) return compare1
        val compare2 = -1 * ord2.compare(x._2, y._2)
        if (compare2 != 0) return compare2
        0
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is not what i am looking for. 
I want to sort the first item, ascending the second descending and so on

Comment: Are these items of the same type?

Comment: I added the last paragraph that says "Please, in your answer consider the following case: .... " And this is actually my use case. I want something that is not hard coded for specific length.

Comment: What do you mean by "length"? This solution is independent of array length. May be your examples of pairs and  Array[Array[People]]  are not connected?

Comment: i edited the question for the full picture. Thanks for your patience.